# dynamic_cast from Base to Derived

Tags: c++, class, dynamic-cast

I have a very general question, related to dynamic_cast in c++:
Let's assume we have the following classes:

```
class Father{ 
public:
       Father(...); // this is constructor
       //.....
       //.. Whatever code in here, not important
       ~ Father(); //destructor 
protected:
      // some protected variables
} // end of class Father


class Son:public Father {
public:
       Son(...); // this is cnostructor
       //.....
       //.. Whatever code in here, not important
       ~ Son(); //destructor 
protected:
      // some protected variables
} // end of class Son


 class Another{
 public:
      Another(...); // this is constructor
       //.....
       //.. Whatever code in here, not important
       ~ Another(); //destructor 

       AnotherMethod(Father* fatherOpj,......) //

} // end of class Another
```

And let's say the method "AnotherMethod" do the next:

```
   AnotherMethod(Father* fatherOpj,......)
   { 
      Son *sonObj = dynamic_cast<Son*>(fatherOpj);
    // using sonObj
   }
```

While in the main we do the following:

```
  Son* son1=Null;
  //...
  son1 = new Son(.....);
 //....
  AnotherMethod(son1,....);
```

Now, I'm wondering about the next issue: that way- when we call AnotherMethod with a pointer of type Son*, while in its signature there's Father*- will we lose the fields/members in son (which father doesn't have)
or that by doing the dynamic_cast we will be able to have them (with the right values inside them)?!

Comment: You will be able to use data members and member functions of `Son` with `sonObj->x`. However, unless this is a contrived example, `Son` probably shouldn't derive from `Father`. Also note that you're not checking if the `dynamic_cast` returned a null pointer.

Comment: Please note that `dynamic_cast` won't work without at least one virtual function, usually the base class destructor.

Comment: @Simple in my own code, I do the casting only if I know for sure that the parameter I get (father* fatherOpj) is a son*, in that case, is there a possibility for null??

Comment: @user2750466 no, but in that case you shouldn't be using `dynamic_cast` but `static_cast` instead.

Comment: @Simple why? is it bad? what would that change if it was static?

Comment: @user2750466 `dynamic_cast` incurs overhead because it has to check whether the object is really the type you're casting it to. If you already know that this is true then you don't need this check, which `static_cast` omits.

Comment: @Simple I'm not that good in c++, so I don't get it, what will dynamic be harmful to? and will both dynamic and static do the job?

Comment: @user2750466: If, as you say, you know *for sure* that the dynamic type is `Son`, then `dynamic_cast` will be doing unnecessary work. `static_cast` would be more efficient, and would work for non-polymorphic types. But it will go horribly wrong if the dynamic type actually isn't `Son`, so `dynamic_cast` is safer if you have the slightest doubt in your assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the pointer really points to a `Son` object (i.e. the *dynamic type* is `Son`, while the *static type* is `Father`), then all of the `Son` fields are there, and are accessible after casting the pointer.

If it doesn't point to `Son`, then the cast will fail, giving a null pointer.

Note that `dynamic_cast` only works if `Father` is polymorphic - that is, if it declares at least one virtual function. In your example, it isn't polymorphic, so the cast will fail.

Comment: And what if the destructor was declared as virtual? will the cast succeed then?

Comment: @user2750466: Yes, any virtual function, including the destructor, will make it polymorphic.

Comment: if I do the casting only if I knew for sure that it points to son, would it be harmful to do dynamic? should I do static in that case? or that both will work?

Comment: @user2750466: It depends what you mean by "harmful". `dynamic_cast` will be slower, but `static_cast` will go horribly wrong if your assumption turns out to be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> will we lose the fields/members in son

No, you just can't access it from pointer to `Father`.

> by doing the dynamic_cast we will be able to have them (with the right
>   values inside them)

Yes, you will, because it's still a `Son` object (if passed object has `Son` type, of course).